# Install Tensorflow on a Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

I have encountered a problem installing tensorflow on a Raspberry Pi 4 B, 32 bit and have been working on it for days without finding a proper solution. I know using a RPi is not optimal, but I do not have an option in the current set up.

Whenever I try to install it using pip, I get "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

I use Python 3.10.7 and Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

I tried using a Python environment I set up earlier on my PC. I also tried using TFLite, but since there seems to be an issue with the tflite-runtime, that did not help either. I also tried to execute my script using sklearn, unfortunately I could not install that either.

From what I searched, there are options to install specific versions on this very model, but for some reason I still could not execute my script.

Comment: Upgrading the OS to 64 bit did the job!